# How to stop navigation barTintColor changes while setting up the tintColor of segment color?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

When I try to change the tint color of SegmentControl, it is changing the navigation bar's barTintColor.

How to stop it please let me know?

This is code for navigation bar appearance
[image]

And this is for segment control

```
internal func wireUpUI() {

        self.selectedSegmentIndex = 0

        //DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tintColor = Color.white

            let segAttributesNormal: NSDictionary = [
                NSForegroundColorAttributeName: Color.white,
                NSFontAttributeName:  UIFont(name: set(), size: fontSize(.medium))!
            ]

            let segAttributesSelected: NSDictionary = [
                NSForegroundColorAttributeName: Color.theme,
                NSFontAttributeName:  UIFont(name: set(), size: fontSize(.medium))!
            ]

            self.setTitleTextAttributes(segAttributesNormal as? [AnyHashable : Any], for: UIControlState.normal)
            self.setTitleTextAttributes(segAttributesSelected as? [AnyHashable : Any], for: UIControlState.selected)
       // }

        // Now bind the data
        bindData(any: [])
    }
```

Comment: Could you add screenshot(s) or some of the code?

Comment: Choose your desired viewController for segmentControl. Create a segmentControl inside of viewDidLoad. Set the tintColor for your segmentControl. And that's it

Comment: I am doing the same

Comment: @GopalDevra Doesn't work?

Comment: @Mannopson, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this inside of `viewDidLoad`:

```
let customSegmentedControl = UISegmentedControl (items: ["one","two","three"])
```

And set the `tintColor` to it.

```
customSegmentedControl.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

Comment: This is works perfectly. If you have tinted as globally

Comment: Actually I think there was issue with the navigation background image.